# Ocaml option function

Tags: pattern-matching, ocaml

I have written this function to calculate the sum of two integers and then output it s a int option type. But I get this warning. I have defined the None case, but I still get this. Can anyone help?

[image: Error]

```
let add x (Some y) = match x with 

|None -> if Some y = None then None
       else Some y
|Some x -> 
  let z = x + y in
  if z > max_int then None 
  else if z < min_int then None
  else if (Some y) = None then Some x 
  else Some (x + y)
```

I did this but still something is missing. Can anyone think of a case where this does not work ?

```
let add x y = match (x, y) with
| (None, None) -> None
| (Some x, None) -> None
| (None, Some y) -> None
| (Some x, Some y) -> if x > max_int then None
                  else if x < 0 then None
                  else if y < 0 then None
                  else if x + y > max x y then None
                  else if x + y < min x y then None
                  else if y > max_int then None
                  else if x < min_int then None
                  else if y < min_int then None
                  else if x + y >= max_int then None
                  else if x + y <= min_int then None
                  else Some (x + y)
```

Comment: It appears that you try to check for overflow; but the way you're doing it can't work. For example, `x > max_int` will never be true, because `max_int` is the biggest value that `x` can have. You may want to check (for example) `x > max_int - y` for the case where both `x` and `y` are positive; this is true iff `x + y > max_int` (subtract `y` on both sides), but avoids overflow.

Comment: Can I test like this 

x + y > max_int - 1?

Comment: No. Aside from an off-by-one error, the problem is that `max_int` is the maximum value that an integer can have in OCaml; if addition overflows, it will wrap around, e.g. `max_int + 1 = min_int`. This is something that you will have to specifically work around (the approach I suggested is not the only one, but probably the easiest if you wish to show it's correct).

Comment: Regarding pattern matching, you can write the case in the new function as `match x, y with | Some x, Some y -> (* all that code *) | _ -> None`. With proper line breaks, of course – I wrote it all in one line because this is a comment.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is here: `let add x (Some y) = ...`.
This defines `add` only in case the second argument isn't `None`.